# iOS How to use touchesMoved to move two images?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, xcode4.3

I have two different `UIImage`s.
I want to allow user to move these images over the `UIView` individually.
How could I do that?

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *image01;
IBOutlet UIImageView *image02;

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
}
```

Comment: could you add this line: `imageToBeMoved.center = location` after you define `CGPoint location =` and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. You can use the standard pan gesture recognizer, one for each `UIImageView`, e.g.:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanImage:)];
image01.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.image01 addGestureRecognizer:pan1];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanImage:)];
image02.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.image02 addGestureRecognizer:pan2];
```

and

```
- (void)handlePanImage:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    static CGPoint originalCenter;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        originalCenter = sender.view.center;
        sender.view.alpha = 0.8;
        [sender.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:sender.view];
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];

        sender.view.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y + translation.y);
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        // do whatever post dragging you want, e.g.
        // snap the piece into place

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            CGPoint center = sender.view.center;
            center.x = round(center.x / 50.0) * 50.0;
            center.y = round(center.y / 50.0) * 50.0;
            sender.view.center = center;
            sender.view.alpha  = 1.0;
        }];
    }
}
```

Or you could create a gesture recognizer on their superview and then use `CGRectContainsPoint` to see if your starting `locationInView` is within the frame of one of your two UIImageViews, and then proceed to animate the appropriate one.

For example, in your view controller, you could create a gesture recognizer:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanSuper:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

And the handler might look like (you could implement as a custom gesture recognizer if you want, too):

```
- (void)handlePanSuper:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    static UIImageView *viewToMove;
    static CGPoint      originalCenter;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.image01.frame, location))
        {
            viewToMove = image01;
            originalCenter = viewToMove.center;
        } 
        else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.image02.frame, location))
        {
            viewToMove = image02;
            originalCenter = viewToMove.center;
        }
        else
        {
            viewToMove = nil;
        }

        if (viewToMove)
        {
            viewToMove.alpha = 0.8;
            [viewToMove.superview bringSubviewToFront:viewToMove];
        }
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged && viewToMove != nil)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];

        viewToMove.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y + translation.y);
    }
    else if ((sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || 
              sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed || 
              sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) && viewToMove != nil)
    {
        // do whatever post dragging you want, e.g.
        // snap the piece into place

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            CGPoint center = viewToMove.center;
            center.x = round(center.x / 50.0) * 50.0;
            center.y = round(center.y / 50.0) * 50.0;
            viewToMove.center = center;
            viewToMove.alpha  = 1.0;
        }];

        viewToMove = nil;
    }
}
```

If I've misunderstood your question, let me know.

Comment: it's ok but I am working on a puzzle game for kids let them collect image pieces together. and sorry for my english.

Comment: @YaserAlNamshan No problem. Strikes me that either of the above techniques should work fine. No need to subclass the recognizer and use if you don't want to. The only question is whether you want a gesture recognizer on each image, or just the one gesture recognizer. By the way, I've updated my code sample with examples of various enancements, e.g. reduce alpha while dragging, move to front so it's not obscured by other images, snapping piece into place at the end, etc. Just something to give you a few ideas.

Comment: Thank you Robert I think I will use this technique :)